# how to direct woocommerce cart content to shop page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi im using this code from woocommerce to insert a cart content on my site. Does somebody know how i can modify this code so if it shows 0 on the cart it will direct me to the shop page instead of the cart page?

```
<?php global $woocommerce; ?>

<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
```

---

```
// Ensure cart contents update when products are added to the cart via AJAX (place the following in functions.php)
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();

    ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
    <?php

    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to shop when cart is empty, you can use action hook 'template_redirect' as follows :

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect' );
function my_template_redirect()
{
    if ( is_page( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) && sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) == 0 )            
    {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

If you are using some other page to show cart content, then you have to modify first condition of if statement, to check if the page is the one that shows cart content.